# DOM APIs in V8 shell

Tags: dom, google-chrome, v8

I have compiled SHELL from standalone Google's V8 javascript engine to run javascript. It works fine until I give a javascript that has DOM API in it. With DOM APIs it gives syntax error. Is there any library that should be included to get this worked?

Answer (score 0):

The stand-alone shell doesn't have the DOM (Document Object Model), since it's not running in a browser that provides the document and DOM implementation.

If you just want to try some DOM code, you might be able to use something like https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim to simulate a DOM. You obviously won't have a real page and it won't be visible anywhere, but it might work for testing purposes.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I had successfully succeeded to extract DOM from chrome and put that with V8. I had to put binding for each and every API in DOM to get it work